# Strange look, jQuery UI

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-dialog

I am using jquery modal dialog, but the look of the dialog is other than the the look of the dialog [example](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal). jquery ui is included and enabled. any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Use Firebug, inspect the dialog element, and see what *other* styles are being applied to it

Comment: Agree with @Yi Jiang, sounds like some global styles are being applied. You may need to override those presets in your stylesheet for the jQuery UI elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like font-size problem. Try to include this line in your page style sheet:

```
body{ font-size: 60% }
```

Comment: ok, now the dialog looks fine, but every other text on my page is too small now^^

Comment: You need to edit css files. Decrease font size in jquery dialog template or increase font size in your page css for all elements except for body. It's up to you.